# Image to Webp to base64

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a javascript script that transforms the images into base64, is it possible before passing it to base64 to transform it into webp to reduce its weight?

In this way I am going to reduce the cost of the database.

```
<input type="file" id="demo">  

<script>
  document.querySelector('#demo').onchange = e => {
  //comprobar medida
  var numb = $('#demo')[0].files[0].size/1024/1024;
  numb = numb.toFixed(2);
  if(numb > 7){
    alert('to big, maximum is 7MB. You file size is: ' + numb +' MB');
    return;
  } else {
    //alert('it okey, your file has ' + numb + 'MB')
  }
  //final comprobar medida
  //transformar a base64
  const fr = new FileReader()
  fr.onloadend = () => SendAjax(fr.result)
  fr.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
}
//final base64
```

Comment: use canvas, example: https://codepen.io/nosilleg/pen/XMdvoM

Comment: I have 2 days from when I turn it over, but I don't understand how to unify the two.